# Search for pattern in a string

Tags: php, algorithm, search, pattern-matching

Pattern search within a string.

for eg.

```
$string = "111111110000";
FindOut($string);
```

Function should return 0

```
function FindOut($str){    
    $items =  str_split($str, 3);    
    print_r($items);
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Also, it's a lot easier for us to answer your question if you include some sample code with how you tried to solve the problem, even if that code doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to break the string into array of 3 characters each and match them all. but none returned.

Comment: How did you break the string into arrays?  Can you edit your answer to show us this code?

Comment: @MikeBrant Solution off course. But in a explainable way, so I can modify according to my need

Comment: Your definition of "occuring twice" is abiguous. Is "101" occurring twice in "00010101"? do you know what I mean?. And what about 1111 in "1111111111" ?

Comment: @G_G yes 101 is occurring twice, no thrice .

Comment: You use str_split wrong. I would fix that first before asking the question. It can not be the right function, see http://php.net/str_split

Comment: thats why I asked for the solution technique

Comment: how about 110101011? i guess the result should be 1 since 101 is occuring twice. but if you split arrays of 3 chars, you won't find that: 110 101 011.

Comment: exactly. Thats why I asked for the solution. I tried mine.

Comment: Why this is marked down.? Some people using their reputation just for fun ?

Comment: I would guess it's because the way the question is currently worded, it's not exactly clear what problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your problem comes down to finding out whether a substring of 3 characters occurs in a string twice without overlapping. This will get you the first occurence's position if it does:

```
function findPattern($string, $minlen=3) {
    $max = strlen($string)-$minlen;
    for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++) {
        $pattern = substr($string,$i,$minlen);
        if(substr_count($string,$pattern)>1)
            return $i;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

What you have here can conceptually be solved with a sliding window. For your example, you have a sliding window of size 3.

For each character in the string, you take the substring of the current character and the next two characters as the current pattern. You then slide the window up one position, and check if the remainder of the string has what the current pattern contains. If it does, you return the current index. If not, you repeat.

Example:

```
1010101101
|-|
```

So, pattern = `101`. Now, we advance the sliding window by one character:

```
1010101101
 |-|
```

And see if the rest of the string has `101`, checking every combination of 3 characters.

Conceptually, this should be all you need to solve this problem.

**Edit:** I really don't like when people just ask for code, but since this seemed to be an interesting problem, here is my implementation of the above algorithm, which allows for the window size to vary (instead of being fixed at 3, the function is only briefly tested and omits obvious error checking):

```
function findPattern( $str, $window_size = 3) {
    // Start the index at 0 (beginning of the string)
    $i = 0;

    // while( (the current pattern in the window) is not empty / false)
    while( ($current_pattern = substr( $str, $i, $window_size)) != false) {
        $possible_matches = array();

        // Get the combination of all possible matches from the remainder of the string
        for( $j = 0; $j < $window_size; $j++) {
            $possible_matches = array_merge( $possible_matches, str_split( substr( $str, $i + 1 + $j), $window_size));
        }

        // If the current pattern is in the possible matches, we found a duplicate, return the index of the first occurrence
        if( in_array( $current_pattern, $possible_matches)) {
            return $i;
        }

        // Otherwise, increment $i and grab a new window
        $i++;
    }
    // No duplicates were found, return -1
    return -1;
}
```

It should be noted that this certainly isn't the most efficient algorithm or implementation, but it should help clarify the problem and give a straightforward example on how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you more want to use a sub-string function to walk along and check every three characters and not just break it into 3

```
function fp($s, $len = 3){
  $max = strlen($s) - $len; //borrowed from lafor as it was a terrible oversight by me
  $parts = array();

  for($i=0; $i < $max; $i++){
    $three = substr($s, $i, $len);
    if(array_key_exists("$three",$parts)){
          return $parts["$three"];  
    //if we've already seen it before then this is the first duplicate, we can return it
    }
    else{
      $parts["$three"] = i; //save the index of the starting position.
    }
  }

  return false; //if we get this far then we didn't find any duplicate strings
}
```

Comment: This finds the matches in an efficient way, but doesn't tell you if a match was found. Could you scan through the string again and find the first length=3 string that has a count in `$parts` greater than 1?

Comment: Are you looking for the first 3 characters that have a repeated value?  Not the most repeated?

Comment: I'm not OP, but OP does seem to be looking for first occurrence based on a [previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13349478/2) of the question.

Comment: @lafor has the solution you seem to be looking for

Comment: He does, but yours runs in linear time and his runs in quadratic time.  So I like yours more. :-)

Comment: I updated the code since you don't really care how many times these happen, and just want the first one, I changed it so that if the array key already exists then we just return that index of the array which now holds the starting index of the string where it can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [`str_split` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php), calling `str_split` on `"1010101101"` will result in:

```
Array(
  [0] => 101
  [1] => 010
  [2] => 110
  [3] => 1
}
```

None of these will match each other.

You need to look at each 3-long slice of the string (starting at index 0, then index 1, and so on).

I suggest looking at [`substr`](http://php.net/substr), which you can use like this:

```
substr($input_string, $index, $length)
```

And it will get you the section of `$input_string` starting at `$index` of length `$length`.

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty implementation of such pattern search:

```
function findPattern($string){
    $matches = 0;
    $substrStart = 0;

    while($matches < 2 && $substrStart+ 3 < strlen($string) && $pattern = substr($string, $substrStart++, 3)){
        $matches = substr_count($string,$pattern);
    }

    if($matches < 2){
        return null;
    }
    return $substrStart-1;
```